# JavaScript get event with closure function?

Tags: javascript

hi i havr problem with get the event and pass it to closure function also i want the (this) varaible

i use

```
   console.log(e);
```

its show undefined >> what the sloution best sloution :)

i try this code

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
a[i].addEventListener("keydown",(function(e){

return function(){
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){

console.log(e);   // e its undefined this is the problem 
console.log(i);   // its get i value no problem here 
//now iam use the closure for get i value
//var that = this;

}

};

 })(e), false);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be referring to in your context?

Comment: What is e supposed to be...your event? Then you want to pass in the function as an event listener *without* calling it with e.

Comment: Your handler returns a function that would successfully log the event, but that returned function is never called!

Comment: this is the elements i add listener to it 

now my problem with e == event its undefined on closure function 
but before closure it work

Comment: Why don't you just write `addEventListener('click', function(e) {... });`? I don't really see the point of using an IIFE here. The event is passed to the *inner* function anyway, not the outer function.

Comment: @Bergi the "handler" in this case is the inner function because he's calling the outer function immediately with a mysterious `e` that he is not telling us about.

Comment: i want to use closure 
return function (){ .... }
its closure function every thing its work inside it this and every other variable 
only the e (event) dosent work its undefined

Comment: Why do you need a closure? There is nothing in your example that would require one.

Comment: If this is a click event why are there `keyCode`'s?

Comment: sorry its not click i will edit it 
its keydown

Comment: Felix Kling >> i want closure because there are loop

Comment: You really have to provide a better example. You are talking about loops, but I don't see any. Currently, the IIFE is unnecessary, it's not clear if you intend `e` to refer to the event that will be triggered or if it is some other variable that already exists.

Comment: Your edit doesn't warrant an IIFE either. You only need one if you are referring to the loop variable in one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly access e inside the function

```
<script>
    a[i].addEventListener("keydown",(function(){
        var index=i;
        return function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
                console.log(this);
                console.log(e);
                console.log(index);
            }
        };
    })(), false);
```

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/wd04hfuv/1)

Comment: but the (e) undefined  this the problem

Comment: @Mohamed: What is `e` supposed to be? The event object for the `keydown` event? If so, this is the correct answer. It seems you are confused by when/how the event object is passed to the handler. But again, there is nothing in your examle that actually warrants an IIFE.

Comment: @Mohamed: Did you actually try my solution to see if it works? Again, even though you claim you "need" an IIFE, you probably don't. In which case, keep it simple.

Comment: @Felix your answer its work but without closure and i need closure

Comment: You should explain why the OP's code didn't work and what you changed.

Comment: @FelixKling if i alert i inside your function then it will alert 4.But this will alert the correct indices. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ankit: You don't have to tell me when/how an IIFE is necessary. My point was that the original example was bad. The current one isn't much better, but I will just assume that the OP really needs to access `i`, for whatever reasons (I'm pretty sure there is a better way, but OP doesn't seem to be willing to provide a proper example for what they are trying to do). SO is for finding the most appropriate solution for a problem, not to give people "what they want" or *think* they need.

Comment: @felix kling  ^__^ xD

Comment: @Shashank `a` is not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array) its a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: Hmmm...ok my mistake. But this is one of the cases where I would consider using `Array.prototype.slice` to convert the NodeList to an array so that the `forEach` method could be used. It's just a lot more readable in my opinion.

Comment: no need to convert, one can use `a.forEach=Array.prototype.forEach` just for object `a`

Comment: Quote from link you posted: *"Note that in the above, passing a host object (like a NodeList) as this to a native method (such as forEach) is not guaranteed to work in all browsers and is known to fail in some."* And the other workaround is: *"One idea would be to add Array.prototype methods to NodeList.prototype. However, be aware that Extending the DOM is dangerous, especially in old version of Internet Explorer (6, 7, 8)."* thus `Array.prototype.slice` is the safest way, albeit inefficient.

Comment: And that some browsers are as usual IE.Well I don't care about IEs<8 but still there is hope for [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method because converting is really a overkill to use one functionality

Comment: apply has the same problem as call, which has the same problem as `a.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach`. The problem is that passing an array-like object as `this` for an array method is not always guaranteed to work (I'm guessing it's because the implementation of Array methods may use some array-only features internally that break when you pass array-like objects to them)

Comment: @Shashank is `Array.prototype.slice` also not passing an array-like object as this for an array method

Comment: @Ankit Yeah good point, but the only time I've seen "don't use slice" is with the `arguments` array-like object because it prevents optimizations or something like that. I don't fully understand it tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the closure to do this. You can use `function.prototype.apply` to call a function and specify what `this` refers to. See here:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    console.log('myFunction', 'event', e);
    console.log('myFunction', 'this', this);
}

var clickBait = document.getElementById('clickBait');

clickBait.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunction.apply(e.target, [e]);
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/vnms6yL1/

If you NEED the closure, can you at least say why? It would help.

Comment: It looks like you went with the other solution. Anyway, just for reference I updated my fiddle with multiple tags. I still don't know why you need a closure for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/vnms6yL1/2/